# How to unregister a S3 method?

Tags: r, r-s3

Let's say I've registered a new S3 method:

```
.S3method("model_package", "lm")
```

Later on, I want to unregister (deregister or remove) the same S3 method, something like:

```
.S3method("model_package", "lm", NULL) # does not work!
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way to unregister S3 methods, in general, because:

1. R doesn't provide an API function for doing it.
2. R doesn't document what registering an S3 method *means*, so even if you wanted to undo the side effects, those side effects could change in a future version of R.

Having said that, for a given version of R (say 4.2.3), we can look at the definition of `.S3method`, determine its side effects, and try to undo them.

Suppose that you've evaluated the following statement in a non-namespace environment `e0`, such as your global environment:

```r
.S3method("f", "a", f.a)
```

Here, `f` is an S3 generic function defined in some environment `e` enclosing `e0`, `a` is the name of a class, and `f.a` is the method (a function) to be registered.

The call to `.S3method` has these side effects:

1. If the name `".__S3MethodsTable__."` does not yet exist in `e`, then it assigns to that name an empty environment enclosed by the **base** environment.
2. It assigns the function `f.a` to the name `"f.a"` in `e[[".__S3MethodsTable__."]]`.

We would undo them in reverse order like so, with the complications that we can't remove bindings from locked environments or change locked bindings:

```r
.S3unmethod <- function(generic, class, envir = NULL) {
    if (is.null(envir)) {
        def <- match.fun(generic)
        envir <- if (typeof(def) == "closure") 
            environment(def) 
        else .BaseNamespaceEnv
    } else stopifnot(exists(generic, envir, mode = "function"))
    s <- ".__S3MethodsTable__."
    if (lock <- bindingIsLocked(s, envir))
        unlockBinding(s, envir)
    envir[[s]][[paste0(generic, ".", class)]] <- NULL
    if (lock)
        lockBinding(s, envir)
    if (length(envir[[s]]) == 0L && !environmentIsLocked(envir))
        envir[[s]] <- NULL
    invisible(NULL)
}

.S3unmethod("f", "a")
```

A more concrete example:

```r
x <- structure(10L, class = "mod2")

.S3method("print", "mod2", function(x, ...) { x <- as.integer(x) %% 2L; NextMethod() })
print(x)
## [1] 0

.S3unmethod("print", "mod2")
print(x)
## [1] 10
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "mod2"
```

Here, `f` is `print`, `a` is `mod2`, `e` is the **base** namespace, and `e0` is (I assume) your global environment.